# windows 7 with deep freeze bypass from ubuntu why?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, boot-partition

why I can bypass deep Freeze by logging in windows partition from Ubuntu and edit what I want is it freeze. I just go to the windows partition file system, then I go to desktop and edit any file I want, then I reboot in windows 7 and I found my file that I edit from Ubuntu. so what is advantage of deep freeze it's useless?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask here?

Comment: log in my Ubuntu and go to windows 7 file system and post something like jpg in windows desktop  , and when boot in windows i found the jpg that i edit ... why that happen although i installed deep freeze in winnows ?

Comment: What is "deep freeze" supposed to do? From Ubuntu, you can of course access, mount and manipulate Windows' partitions.

Comment: Is 'Deep freeze' a new word teens are using these days for  Linux's capacity to work on Windows-based File-system?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_%28software%29

Comment: It appears that you are having an issue with the Windows application Deep Freeze, and should ask this question on a Windows site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_%28software%29), Deep Freeze cannot protect you in this case:

> **Deep Freeze cannot protect the operating system and hard drive upon
>   which it is installed if the computer is booted from another medium**
>   (**such as another bootable partition** or internal hard drive, an
>   external hard drive, a USB device, optical media, or network server).
>   In such cases, a user would have real access to the contents of the
>   (supposedly) frozen system.[3] On a Windows-based computer, this
>   scenario may be prevented by configuring the CMOS (nonvolatile BIOS
>   memory) on the workstation to boot only to the hard drive to be
>   protected, then password protecting the CMOS. This is a normal
>   precaution for most public access computers. A further precaution
>   would be to lock the PC case shut with a physical lock or tiedown
>   cable system to prevent access to motherboard jumpers.